# INSERT INTO SELECT WHERE, checking for duplicated entries

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-into

I have an `INSERT INTO SELECT` query modeled below and it works functionally.  What is not included, but I would like to include is a way to check if the `INSERT INTO` data already exists in the `wa_research` table.

```
INSERT INTO wa_research C 
            (field1, 
             field2, 
             field3, 
             field4, 
             field5, 
             field6, 
             field7, 
             field8, 
             field9, 
             field10) 
SELECT A.field1, 
       A.field2, 
       A.field3, 
       A.field4, 
       A.field5, 
       A.field6, 
       A.field7, 
       A.field8, 
       A.field9, 
       A.field10 
FROM   wa_tmp_listed A 
       LEFT JOIN wa_list B 
              ON A.field2 = B.field2 
WHERE  B.field2 IS NULL
```

I want to check before inserting into `wa_research` and skip the rows that have the combination of `C.field1`, `C.field2`, `C.field3` in the `wa_research` table.

I assume I can do this with an additional `JOIN`, so if you have a suggestion or example and/or guide me on the type of extended `JOIN`, I am looking to do that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a condition to the `WHERE` clause and use `NOT EXIST` with a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO wa_research C (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5,
                           field6, field7, field8, field9, field10)
SELECT A.field1, A.field2, A.field3, A.field4, A.field5,
                 A.field6, A.field7, A.field8, A.field9, A.field10
FROM wa_tmp_listed A
LEFT JOIN wa_list B ON A.field2 = B.field2
WHERE B.field2 IS NULL
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                 FROM wa_research CC
                 WHERE CC.field1 = A.field1
                   AND CC.field2 = A.field2
                   AND CC.field3 = A.field3)
```

Comment: Racil - Thank you for your suggested solution.  I've looked at this and attempted to make it work, but I'm getting an MySQL #1064 error.  I'm working to debug it, but can you help me understand better your alias naming the second instance of the wa_research table as CC and then mapping it to CC.C.field1, etc.     thank you.

Comment: The second alias `CC` is just an alias, you can use anything else if you want. You already used the alias `C`, so I needed another alias, but you can change it to `C2` for example. The mapping `CC.C.field1 = C.field1` is a typo, it should be `CC.field1 = A.field1`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Racil - After working through this for awhile and checking to make sure I have spelled all of the fields correctly, SQL syntax, etc.  Wondering if I don't have the order correct in that maybe the continued MySQL #1064 error is related to not having data that ties to those fields?  there is data in wa_research, there is data in wa_tmp_listed and there is data in wa_list, but would they match up based on the query order?

Comment: Additionally, the error has moved to this part of the query.  (SELECT * FROM wa_research CC
                WHERE CC.field1 = A.field1
                  AND CC.field2 = A.field2
                  AND CC.field3 = A.field3)

Comment: Solved.  I was overlooking and using EXIST vs. EXISTS in the following line: WHERE B.field2 IS NULL AND NOT EXIST.   I changed to WHERE B.field2 IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS and it worked.  Thank you to Racil for your help in guiding me on this question.

Comment: Yes, it must be `EXISTS`, I've updated my answer. The main problem we face in answering questions on SO is the lack of ability to test and verify our answers. I'm glad it worked for you.